# Оптимизация сайта но скорости

Tags: python, django, nginx, pagespeed-insights, gunicorn

Появилась очень странная проблема со скоростью сайта.

- OS: ubuntu server 18.04
- Proxy Server: Nginx + Pagespeed
- WSGI Server: Gunicorn
- FW: Django 1.11.5

Проблемы:

- Время окончания работы ЦП - 12,4 сек.
- Приблизительное время задержки    при вводе - 220 мс
- Время загрузки для взаимодействия - 14,8 сек

Диагностика подсказывает:

- Минимизируйте работу в основном потоке - 6,9 сек
- Сократите время выполнения кода JavaScript - 3,6 сек((Google maps +
  Google recapcha))
- Задайте правила эффективного использования кеша для статических
  объектов - 8 ресурса (Google maps + Google recapcha)

Всё вышеперечисленное относится к Мобильной версии сайта 44 из 100, на ПК версии всё норм - 90 из 100

Возможно проблема в конфиге сервиса, но не уверен.

```
[Unit]
Description=site.com django instance
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple

User=www-data
Group=www-data

Restart=always
RestartSec=2

Environment="IS_PRODUCTION=yes"
Environment="PYTHONPATH=/home/rast/src"

#ExecStart=/home/site/app/bin/gunicorn main.wsgi
ExecStart=/home/site/app/bin/gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 --workers 3 --threads 2 main.wsgi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Отзовитесь если кто то знаком с подобными проблемами

Comment: Так это всё совершенно не связано с сервером, тормозят же html/css/javascript

Comment: Открываем инструменты разработчика в хроме, профилировщик в руки и вперёд искать тормозящие места в коде

Comment: Дело в том что там уже всё отптимизировано(js/css/img минифицирован лишнее и так убрано) Минимизируйте работу в основном потоке - 6,9 сек - этот показатель вроде бы ни как не связан с вышеперечисленным

Comment: Очевидно, имеется в виду основной поток javascript-кода. Минификация не является оптимизацией javascript-кода и совершенно никак не влияет на его производительность и производительность основного потока.

Comment: ну предположим, а что в таком случае делать? Код который уже присутствует, он нужен(Рекапча, Прокрутки, слайдер, Карты и тп)

Comment: Брать профилировщик в руки, изучать код и разбираться, что в нём можно соптимизировать

Comment: Выбрал пять тегов и угадал ни один :) тут скорее должны быть Javascript, html и css